# How can I conditional do an ng-repeat based the number I need?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm pulling data from a local SQLite database and using `ng-view` to populate a screen. The data is repeated with `ng-repeat` based on the number of items returned. The page needs to have 6 items at all times. I'm able to get the total number in my scope as `$scope.productCount`. This number can be between 0 and 6.

What I want to do is run an additional `ng-repeat` for the remainder. Meaning if I only return 4 I need it to repeat twice. However, if I get 6 back I don't need it to repeat at all.

I thought about doing something like

```
ng-repeat="i in getNumber(6 - productCount) ng-show="productCount < 6"
```

and using this in my controller

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

I'm not sure if 1) this is the correct way. 2) If my idea will work. I don't want to go down that rabbit hole if it's a bust.

Comment: To get the remainder use the Modulus operator `6 % 4 = 2`. If it's correct let me know so I can put up the answer ;)

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear to me. Is it like you want a minimum of 6 items and repeat the items if its less than six?

Comment: I updated the question for the ng-repeat. Basically I need to repeat the remainder on if the results are less than 6

Answer (score 0):

what about using filter method.

```
ng-repeat='i in productCount | limitTo:4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div ng-if="productCount < 6">
       <div ng-repeat="data in productCount">

       </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(not sure if I get your problem right)

You can create custom filter to repeat array items if there is less than desired items count.

```
MyApp.filter("arrayItemsRepeat", function () {
    return function (array, count) {
        var i = 0;

        while(array.length < count) {
            array.push(array[i]);
            i++;
        }

        return array;
    }
});
```

and then use the filter in template:

```
ng-repeat='item in items | arrayItemsRepeat:6'
```